# Has anybody desired using chancejs like this: Chance.string(); rather than const chance = new Chance(); chance.string();

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, random

When unit testing in a JavaScript/TypeScript project I have found great value in using chancejs (https://chancejs.com). But in each different spec file I have to instantiate a new instance of chance like so:

### Example with instances:

```
//Spec 1
const chance = new Chance();
const personMock = {
    firstName: chance.name(),
    age: chance.integer(),
};

//Spec 2
const chance = new Chance();
const addressMock = {
    address: chance.address(),
    isApartment: chance.bool(),
};
```

I have not discovered a need for a chance instance, except when a known seed is declared (https://chancejs.com/usage/seed.html). In all cases where it is not desireable to use a seed, it seems like instantiating chance is only extra overhead.

**Question 1:** Has anybody desired using chance in the same way we use Math.random()?

### Example without instances:

```
//Spec 1
const personMock = {
    firstName: Chance.name(),
    age: Chance.integer(),
};

//Spec 2
const addressMock = {
    address: Chance.address(),
    isApartment: Chance.bool(),
};
```

**Question 2:** Can you foresee any drawbacks to doing so?

Comment: Do whatever you like, I suspect that calling `Chance` properties just uses an internally-created instance anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of [chancejs](https://chancejs.com/) is to

> to help reduce some monotony particularly while writing automated tests or anywhere else you need anything random

I definitely think it is monotonous to create a new instance of Chance throughout the software. There is no need for more than one instance as the underlying mechanism that produces the random value is the same across instances.

I would appreciate someone to update chancejs to have include access to a const instance of chance.